# React Native Local Push Notification with Expo App

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am developing a `react-native` app with `expo-cli` tools using `Visual Studio Code`. No `java` code and Android Studio stuff.

I used `react-native-push-notification` as a library but it always gives me error about `RNPushNotification is null`.

I searched for the issue all over web and their git repo. But mostly no luck as their solution was for Android Studio Code.

Is there any way to solve this with a plain expo app? Is there any other alternative for local push notifications on android react native app build with expo?

**Demo Code I am using**

**LocalPushController.js**

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

PushNotification.configure({
  // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log("LOCAL NOTIFICATION ==>", notification);
  },

  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});

export const LocalNotification = () => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    autoCancel: true,
    bigText:
      "This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.",
    subText: "Local Notification Demo",
    title: "Local Notification Title",
    message: "Expand me to see more",
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 300,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: "default",
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]',
  });
};

export const ScheduledLocalNotification = () => {
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    autoCancel: true,
    bigText:
      "This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.",
    subText: "Local Notification Demo",
    title: "Scheduled Notification Title",
    message: "Scheduled Notification Message",
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 500,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: "default",
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]',
    date: new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 1000), // in 3 secs
  });
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React,{Component} from "react"
export default class App extends Component{
    getNotif=()=>{
        LocalNotification();
    }

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Button 
                onPress={this.getNotif} 
                title="Get Notification">
            </Button>
        </View>
)
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/)

Comment: Thank you @Kartikey, Will this work on local notification when app is installed finally without expo client as in testing right now?

Comment: Yes, it will work Perfectly! You may need to do some configurations for `Push Notifications`,  but for `Local Notifications` you don't need to worry. It will work.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much, I will update the progress.